# How to define alias for command which will be available in shell script?

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Here is a part of my `.bashrc`

```
alias my_command="my_command -1 -2 -3"
```

and its my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
my_command blah blah blah
```

It occurs into error

```
./aa: line 2: my_command: command not found
```

So, how to define aliases for the command in the right way?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have for `my_command` in your file?

Comment: for example, I want to define `java` as `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/bin/java` and NOT as `/usr/bin/java`

Answer (score 2):

Two things that happen in interactive shells (expansion of aliases and sourcing of your `.bashrc`) do not occur when you run a script. You could try adding the following to the top of your script:

```
source ~/.bashrc         # To get the alias
shopt -s expand_aliases  # To allow alias expansion in your script
```

You might consider changing `mycommand` to a shell function; then you wouldn't have to enable alias expansion in your script.

```
mycommand () {
    my_command -1 -2 -3 "$@"
}
```

Comment: Where I can place shell function definition which will be available in shell script without usage of `source` command? Is it possible?

Comment: Not in any way I would recommend. `bash` doesn't automatically source any files for non-interactive shells, which is what the script runs in. This is a feature, as you want your script to behave deterministically, not at the whim of the environment of whoever happens to run it. You have to put the function in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

`alias my_command="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/bin/java"`

After this type

`source .bashrc`

After typing `source .bashrc` are you getting any error?

Comment: but in separate script, with doesn't use `source` because its written by other people, this fail. Is there any way to set up alias for any fork or shell interpreter?

Comment: If the script is written by other people, why would it use an alias defined in your personal `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention it to use a specific version of Java, then you might want to define `JAVA_HOME` and set `PATH` variable accordingly.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/bin/java
export PATH=$PATH:export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
```

If it's about just setting an alias, then the syntax you used is correct (of course, with some valid commands)

```
alias lm="ls -l"
```

Comment: How I can apply this settings in fork of shell interpreter started this `#!/bin/sh` pragma?